# Proxycurl API doesnt return data properly

Tags: python, firebase, rest, screen-scraping

Let me first explain quickly the workflow, User enters a search query -> making a search in linkedin with this query -> grabbing urls of users (in function of nb of pages) -> search for these users in proxycurl (https://nubela.co/proxycurl/docs#people-api-person-lookup-endpoint) -> grab their infos with a function -> store them in my db -> grabs infos about the experiences of the scraped users -> make a search in proxycurl API again but for the companies this time -> grab infos about companies and store them in db -> search infos about employees in this company (https://nubela.co/proxycurl/docs#company-api-employee-search-api-endpoint) -> grab url of the CTO -> search in the contact API to grab the infos about the CTO (https://nubela.co/proxycurl/docs#contact-api-personal-contact-number-lookup-endpoint and https://nubela.co/proxycurl/docs#contact-api-personal-email-lookup-endpoint) -> store everything in database.

Ok so I manage to grab URLs, search for the users in API, but I never manage to get the 'extra' information with my code while I can grab them for the same profiles in Postman, same for `personnal_email`, `personnal_contact_number`, `github_profile_id`.
Then I manage to grab the data about the companies, but still same problem, can't retrieve the 'extra' information, or the `funding_data` or `acquisitions` even if I include them in my code.

I really don't know what's wrong with my code (I'm assuming something's wrong because everything works perfectly with Postman), and I can take a little help here (Full code below).

```
from telnetlib import EC
import requests
from datetime import datetime
import json
import re 
from cgitb import text
import selenium
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString, Tag 
from time import sleep
from time import time 
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import csv
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import db
import openpyxl
import requests


cred = credentials.Certificate(r"C:\Users\radia\Downloads\st-londres-2-firebase-adminsdk-7eowq-786e799875.json")
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
    'databaseURL': 'https://st-londres-2-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/'
})


print('- Importation des packages')
# Task 1: webdriver configuration 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
# Task 1.1: Open Chrome and Access Linkedin 
sleep(2)
url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/login'
driver.get(url)
print('Initialisation du chrome driver')
sleep(2)

# Task 1.2: Import username and password
credential = open(r"C:\Users\radia\OneDrive\Bureau\credentials.txt")
line = credential.readlines()
username = line[0]
password = line[1]
print('Importation des id')
sleep(2)

# Task 1.2: Key in login credentials
email_field = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'username')
email_field.send_keys(username)
print('Email ok')
sleep(3)

password_field = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'session_password')
password_field.send_keys(password)
print('Mdp ok')
sleep(2)

# Task 1.2: Click the Login button
signin_field = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="organic-div"]/form/div[3]/button')
signin_field.click()
sleep(3)

print('- Task A: Connexion à Linkedin')

search_field = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="global-nav-typeahead"]/input')

search_query = input('Type of profile to scrape ')

search_field.send_keys(search_query)

search_field.send_keys(Keys.RETURN) 

print('TASK B OK')
sleep(10)
try: 
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='search-reusables__filters-bar']/ul/li[2]/button").click()

except selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
    print("Element not found")


def GetURL(): #function to grab linkedin urls 
    page_source = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, features='lxml')
    a_elements = page_source.find_all('a', {'class': "app-aware-link"})
    all_urls = []
    for element in a_elements:
        url = element.get('href')
        all_urls.append(url)
    return all_urls

##Pagination 
sleep(2)
input_page = int(input('Nombre de pages à scraper: '))
URLs_all_page = []
for page in range(input_page):
    URLs_one_page = GetURL()
    sleep(2)
    driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);') #scrolling to the end of the page
    sleep(3)
    next_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[contains(@class, "artdeco-pagination__button--next") and .//li-icon]')
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", next_button)
    sleep(2) 
    if URLs_one_page is not None:
        URLs_all_page = URLs_all_page + URLs_one_page
        print(URLs_all_page)
    else:
        print('variable stores a None value')
        sleep(2)
        print(URLs_all_page)
sleep(1)        
    
def get_profile_info(url): # function to make api calls for users 
    api_endpoint = 'https://nubela.co/proxycurl/api/v2/linkedin'
    api_key = 'SDrD73S2fXlvCMdFDExEaw'
    headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + api_key}
    params = {
        'url': url,
        'fallback_to_cache': 'on-error',
        'use_cache': 'if-present',
        'skills': 'include',
        'inferred_salary': 'include',
        'personal_email': 'include',
        'personal_contact_number': 'include',
        'twitter_profile_id': 'include',
        'facebook_profile_id': 'include',
        'github_profile_id': 'include', 
        'extra': 'include',
    }
    try:
        response = requests.get(api_endpoint, headers=headers, params=params)
        if response.status_code != 404:
            data_profile = response.json()
            return data_profile
        else:
            return None
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print (e)
        return None

def get_company_info(url): #function to make api calls for companies 
    api_key = 'SDrD73S2fXlvCMdFDExEaw'
    headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + api_key}
    api_endpoint = 'https://nubela.co/proxycurl/api/linkedin/company'
    params = {
    'resolve_numeric_id': 'true',
    'categories': 'include',
    'funding_data': 'include',
    'extra': 'include',
    'exit_data': 'include',
    'acquisitions': 'include',
    'url': 'include',
    'use_cache': 'if-present',
}
    try:
        response = requests.get(api_endpoint, params={'url':url}, headers=headers)
        if response.status_code == 404:
            print("Company not found for URL:", url)
            return None
        else:
            data_company = response.json()
            print(data_company)
            if 'extra' in data_company:
                print("Extra information found:", data_company['extra'])
            else:
                print("No extra information found in JSON response.")
            return data_company

    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print (e)
        return None 

def get_company_employee_url(company_linkedin_profile_url):
    api_endpoint = 'https://nubela.co/proxycurl/api/linkedin/company/employee/search/'
    api_key = 'SDrD73S2fXlvCMdFDExEaw'
    header_dic = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + api_key}
    params = {
        'page_size': '10',
        'linkedin_company_profile_url': company_linkedin_profile_url,
        'keyword_regex': '[Cc][Tt][Oo]',
        'enrich_profiles': 'enrich',
        'resolve_numeric_id': 'false',
    }
    response = requests.get(api_endpoint,
                            params=params,
                            headers=header_dic)
    print(response.status_code)
    print(response.text)
    if response.status_code == 404:
        print("No employees found for URL:", url)
        return None
    else:
        data_employees = response.json()
        if 'employees' in data_employees:
            print("Employees found:", data_employees['employee_search_results'])
        else:
            print("No employees found in JSON response.")
        #return and store profile_url in data_employees:
        for employee in data_employees['employee_search_results']:
           profile_url = employee['profile_url']
           print(profile_url)
    
def get_company_employee_info(profile_url):
    api_endpoint = 'https://nubela.co/proxycurl/api/contact-api/personal-contact'
    api_key = 'SDrD73S2fXlvCMdFDExEaw'
    header_dic = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + api_key}
    params = {
        'linkedin_profile_url': 'https://linkedin.com/in/test-phone-number',
    }
    response = requests.get(api_endpoint,
                            params=params,
                            headers=header_dic)
# Initialize visited URLs + data_list 

visited_urls = []

for url in URLs_all_page:
    if url in visited_urls:
        print("Profile already exists in the database for URL:", url)
        continue
    data = get_profile_info(url)
    if data and "error" in data:
        print(data["error"])
    if not data or "experiences" not in data:
        continue
    data["search_query"] = search_query  # Add the search_query to the data
    db.reference('profiles').push(data)  # Store data in the candidates table
    
    visited_urls.append(url)
    print("Profile data and search query successfully added to the candidates table for URL:", url)

    for item in data['experiences']:
        company_name = str(item['company'])
        company_name_push = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9]', '', company_name) # Error handling when pushing code to db, replacement of illegal values 
        company_linkedin_profile_url = item['company_linkedin_profile_url']
        company_description = item['description']
        company_data = get_company_info(company_linkedin_profile_url)
        if company_name_push:
            filtered_company = db.reference('companies/'+ company_name_push).get()
        else:
            continue

        if filtered_company is None:
            db.reference('companies').push({
                'company_name': company_name_push,
                'company_linkedin_profile_url': company_linkedin_profile_url, 
                'company_description': company_description,
                'company_data': company_data
            })
            print("Company data successfully added for URL:", company_linkedin_profile_url)
        else:
            print("Company already exists in the database for URL:", company_linkedin_profile_url)

        experiences = {
            'candidate_name': data['full_name'], 
            'title': item['title'], 
            'company': item['company'], 
            'location': item['location'],
            'start_date': item['starts_at'],
            'end_date': item['ends_at'],
            'description': item['description'],
        }
        db.reference('experiences').push(experiences) 
        
        company_employee_url = get_company_employee_url(company_linkedin_profile_url)
        company_employee_data = get_company_employee_info(company_employee_url)

        if company_employee_data:
            db.reference('company_employees/' + company_name_push).push(company_employee_data)
            print("Company employee data successfully added for company:", company_name)
        else:
            print("No data found for company employees for company:", company_name)
```

Comment: try to shorten you problem text and also condense your code snippet, so it can be read to the point

Comment: I think you leaked your API key.

Answer (score 1):

The gist is that Proxycurl API returns extra information on a best effort basis. If it does not have results, it will not be returned.